# JavaScript or jQuery: jump to div on separate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a website that I work on which is trying to branch out into social networking.  The social site they're wanting to use has an add for them.  However on the page there is a HUGE header area before the ad for the company.  So much so that you don't even see their add on the page when you get there.

I'm wanting to know if it's when doing the redirect to have it redirect to the page and go to the specific div in question.  Haven't been able to figure it out since there isn't an anchor on the other page.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash tags at the end of the URLs work with anchor names and ids. Therefore, if the div has an id of `mydiv` , or if there's a named anchor next to it (`<a name="mydiv"></a>`)you can  navigate to `url.com/page.html#mydiv`

Otherwise, you're out of luck if the page is on a different server because your JS can't modify/access pages on different servers